# Determine constraint constant while it is animating

Tags: ios, swift, animation, autolayout

I've got a view controller set up with a top and bottom view like so:

```
----------------
|              |
|              |
|              |
|              |
---------------- < constraint with constant of 250
|              |
|              |
|              |
|              |
----------------
```

Using AutoLayout in IB, I've set each of the views to conform to the outside of the parent and given the center constraint a constant of 250.

I then have an IBOutlet to the center constraint which I can animate:

```
// MARK: - View Containers
@IBOutlet weak public var topView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak public var bottomView: UIView!

// MARK: - Constraints
@IBOutlet weak var splitViewDividerConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

And animating:

```
func animateConstraint() {
    splitViewDividerConstraint.constant = someNumber

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

Under certain circumstances I need to determine whether or not the constraint is above or below specific y positions (let's say when it moves up past a `y` point of 100 or less, or down past a `y` point of 400 or greater).

This works fine so long as the constraint isn't animating, but if it is, because I'm technically setting the constraint constant before the animation begins, it always returns the destination constraint position, which will be inaccurate if the constraint animation is still occurring.

**Is there a way to retrieve the current position of a constraint while it is being animated?**

Comment: I would recommend to do key value observing on that particular property. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html ctrl+F Key-Value Observing.

Comment: As soon as you set `splitViewDividerConstraint.constant = someNumber` the constraint's constant value is `someNumber`. It will remain that thought the animation. If you would like to know the size of view while it is animating you need to look at `myAnimatingView.layer.presentationLayer.frame`. For more information consider watching: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/216/

Comment: Ah, @beyowulf nice catch. For that matter, I didn't even have to dig that deep - I was able to use the `y` origin of the bottom view, which is constrained like this. Still, even though I've solved it, I think the question is still a good one that should be answered by observing the constraint, per NSGangster's comment.

Comment: No KVO will not work. Constraint based animations are not performed by repeatedly assigning new values to an `NSLayoutConstraint`'s `constant` property. It is done by performing a layout pass which updates a view's frame, which in turn updates its `CALayer`. The model layer will have the final frame applied immediately. The `presentationLayer` will reflect the onscreen value, (i.e. what you're actually seeing.). KVO might fire for the initial setting of the `constant` value, but not again.

Comment: He could do KVO or both of the `UIView`'s frames, which should get observed during animation and of which he can calculate from there what the constraints constant should be.

Comment: Alright, so sounds like it's not technically possible. @beyowulf if you want to add an answer that describes that and why, I'll accept.

Comment: @brandonscript I know it might sound bad but if the other ways mentioned above aren't possible isn't one obvious (might be naive in this case) way is to a run a timer and have it update the constraint every x seconds (well aware this may not be the best answer).

Comment: @TPN1994 the frame solution works fine - but thanks

Comment: @brandonscript it does seem that, incredibly, you can't get "the new constraint" - it seems you just have to use the frame and back-calculate.  Wild!