# How do I make CAAnimation call my custom function in each frame?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, caanimation

In my custom view, I have a mask layer:

```
let path = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
let layer = CAShapeLayer()
layer.path = path.cgPath
view.layer.mask = layer
```

Now I want to animate this mask layer, changing the `rect` path to a different shape. But the path is not an "animatable" property, can I make CAAnimation to call my custom function to update the path in each frame?

I know about `CAKeyframeAnimation`, but I hope there is a more elegant way to do this.

@jrturton 's comment solved my problem. But just out of curiosity, I am wondering if it is possible to invoke a custom function for every frame of CABasicAnimation.

Comment: The path of a shape layer is animatable. As long as the paths have a similar number of points it usually does a good job of interpolating them in an animation for you - what is the new and old path you are going for?

Comment: Both paths are rectangles. Yes, this is animatable, quite out of my expectation.

Comment: have a look at this thread, maybe it'll point you in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330146/determine-constraint-constant-while-it-is-animating#comment79623587_46330146

Comment: Yes you can do it on a per frame basis but it would not look any different. If you want to make it have a stop motion you could loop an array for the number of points and set them as keytimes for a CAKeyFrameAnimation. Suppose I was animating sometime to 10 my values might look like [0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5....]. And Suppose it was 5 seconds the values might me [0,.05,.01,.15,.20] with a duration of 10. Was doing this in my head as I typed but hope this helps